# VS 2012 Performance Profiler on x64

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Has anyone tried to profile like WCF webservice or any C# project in the Visual Studio 2012 (64-bit) running on x64 machine? I'm getting failed to load WoW64 symbols and dlls when profiling. It profiles, but because of the failure the report doesn't really contain data.

> Failed to load symbols for C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll Failed to
>   load symbols for C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll Failed to load
>   symbols for C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
>   Failed to load symbols for
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Failed to load
>   symbols for C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll Failed to load symbols
>   for C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll Failed to
>   load symbols for C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll Failed to load
>   symbols for C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll Failed to load symbols for
>   C:\Windows\System32\wow64.dll

Comment: @HansPassant Page no longer available in case anyone else finds this question as I did.